# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pytz

I have a problem installing [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) in virtualenv.

> Downloading/unpacking pytz
>         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from versions: 2009r, 2008b, 2009f, 2008c, 2007g, 2011g, 2005m, 2011e, 2007f, 2011k, 2007k, 2006j, 2008h, 2008i, 2011e, 2008a, 2009e, 2006g, 2011j, 2010l, 2005m, 2008i, 2005k, 2008g, 2007c, 2007i, 2009l, 2009r, 2006j, 2011k, 2007d, 2006p, 2009i, 2009u, 2007i, 2009f, 2010g, 2008h, 2009a, 2007g, 2011e, 2006p, 2012b, 2010k, 2005r, 2007f, 2009l, 2009p, 2008c, 2009j, 2008g, 2010g, 2010h, 2011h, 2010k, 2007c, 2007d, 2011d, 2009l, 2011c, 2008a, 2005m, 2007k, 2009n, 2011d, 2010o, 2013b, 2012h, 2010e, 2012c, 2012d, 2012f, 2011n, 2011b, 2011j, 2008c, 2012j, 2007k, 2009f, 2009d, 2010e, 2010b, 2013b, 2011d, 2009p, 2008h, 2005r, 2009i, 2009n, 2009a, 2010k, 2008g, 2006g, 2008b, 2012c, 2009i, 2007g, 2012c, 2010h, 2011n, 2012g, 2007d, 2008a, 2009u, 2012g, 2010o, 2006p, 2010b, 2009u, 2012d, 2011k, 2012f, 2009a, 2007f, 2011h, 2010l, 2009j, 2011g, 2009g, 2009g, 2005r, 2011c, 2012g, 2009g, 2012d, 2009j, 2010o, 2007c, 2010g, 2006g, 2009d, 2010h, 2005k, 2006j, 2010b, 2009n, 2011g, 2011c, 2012b, 2009e, 2009d, 2011j, 2007i, 2012j, 2010l, 2009r, 2012h, 2010e, 2009p, 2008i, 2012f, 2009e, 2012b, 2011h, 2005k, 2008b, 2013b, 2011n, 2012j, 2004b)
>       Cleaning up...
>       No distributions matching the version for pytz

It seems like it's a problem with the latest version of pip.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try `pip install --pre pytz`.

Comment: @falsetru That comment should be on Bold 72.

Comment: If you are trying to install askbot run the above first and seems to fix the issue if "pip install askbot" fails on installing pytz. Had the issue trying to install askbot on Amazon's Ubuntu's 12.04 AMI.

Comment: Good news: --pre is no longer needed: Version Numbering Scheme changed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1224858

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This error occurs when installing `pytz` using pip v1.4 or newer, due to this change in behaviour:

> ### [Pre-release Versions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.1/logic.html#pre-release-versions)
>
> Starting with v1.4, pip will only install stable versions as specified by [PEP426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426) by default. If a version cannot be parsed as a compliant [PEP426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426) version then it is assumed to be a pre-release.
>
> If a Requirement specifier includes a pre-release or development version (e.g. `>=0.0.dev0`) then pip will allow pre-release and development versions for that requirement. This does not include the `!=` flag.
>
> The `pip install` command also supports a `--pre` flag that will enable installing pre-releases and development releases.

The version identifiers for the `pytz` package have a format like `2013b`. [PEP426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426) uses the version identifiers described in [PEP440](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440), which specifies that:

> Public version identifiers MUST comply with the following scheme:
>
> ```
> N[.N]+[{a|b|c|rc}N][.postN][.devN]
> ```

Because the `pytz` versions like `2013b` do not match this format, version 1.4+ of pip is treating *all* versions of `pytz` as pre-release versions, and is not installing them by default.

If you are only installing `pytz`, you can use the `--pre` flag to avoid this behaviour, but you wouldn't want to use this flag for installing your entire project's requirements: some packages might have unstable pre-release versions you don't want. In that case, use the behaviour described above: if you specify a "pre-release" version number for the package, then pip will search for "pre-release" versions of the package. So I've added this to my `requirements.txt`:

```
pytz>=2013b
```

When I upgrade my packages, pip will now correctly search for and install  the latest version of `pytz`.

This has been filed as [issue #1204837 in the pytz bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1204837) and [issue #974 in the pip bug tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/974).

**Stop Press**: As described in the [PyTz bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1204837), the version numbering of pytz has now been changed to, for example, 2013.7 - so once you have upgraded to this, the problem should no longer occur.

Comment: The [updated PEP 440](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#olson-database-versioning) seems to say that pytz should be using the format 0.2013.6, not 2013.6. Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a student. I was learning pytz(downloaded, Run, command prompt then tried IntelliJ, Project Structure, SDKS) and it would not import even after deleting, redoing the files. Read the Launchtype bug list. I switched to pendulum. It worked with prior script that used pytz. Just an idea not a direct answer. Original script was Buchalka (teaching Python3 script in a lesson and lesson would not work with IntelliJ) with pytz. Adapted script to pendulum(Intellij,Project Structure, SDKS, +) so I could experience timezone. (no indents with this block of code) Posting since a search of Internet sites did not reveal much help to solve pytz. Pendulum offered an alternative.

```
import pendulum
import datetime
country = "Europe/Paris"

tz_to_display = pendulum.timezone(country)
local_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz_to_display)
print("The time in {} is {}".format(country, local_time))
print("UTC is {}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
```

For those with more knowledge and more complicated script here is the pendulum site. https://pendulum.eustace.io/blog/a-faster-alternative-to-pyz.html
A library exists for pendulum on the site. It states ( SÉBASTIEN EUSTACE)

This is due to the fact that Pendulum relies heavily on the presence of the fold attribute which was introduced in Python 3.6.

The reason it works inside the Pendulum ecosystem is that it backported the fold attribute in the DateTime class.

Comment: tmi - You can certainly shorten your answer and give a more precise one.