# pip install icalendar: pytz not found

Tags: python, pip, pytz

I try to install icalendar on our local pypi server:

The first attempt failed, now I know that I need to use --pre for pytz. But nevertheless the dependency can't be found:

```
(pypi)pypi@gray:~> pip install --pre  -d packages  pytz
Downloading/unpacking pytz
  Downloading pytz-2013d.tar.bz2 (204kB): 204kB downloaded
Saved ./packages/pytz-2013d.tar.bz2
Running setup.py egg_info for package pytz

  warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'pytz'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'test_zdump.py'
Successfully downloaded pytz
Cleaning up...
```

Now I try to install icalendar:

```
(pypi)pypi@gray:~> pip install -d packages icalendar
Downloading/unpacking icalendar
  File was already downloaded packages/icalendar-3.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package icalendar

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'src/icalendar'
Downloading/unpacking setuptools (from icalendar)
  File was already downloaded packages/setuptools-1.1.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package setuptools

Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil (from icalendar)
  File was already downloaded packages/python-dateutil-2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-dateutil

Downloading/unpacking pytz (from icalendar)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from icalendar) (from versions: 2010b, 2012f, 2010e, 2005m, 2011e, 2010l, 2010e, 2009u, 2008c, 2006j,... 2013d, 2013d, 2012h, 2011h, 2013b, 2012d, 2004b)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pytz (from icalendar)
Storing complete log in /home/pypi/.pip/pip.log
```

Any hint how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried to keep `--pre` while installing `icalendar`?

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. See the link the my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz)

in older versions the numbering scheme of pytz was not compatible with pip.

This changed. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1224858