# Downloading/unpacking Error installing googledatastore

Tags: pip, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying out googleDataStore  with the tutorial using pip 1.5.4

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_python/

I am running on a Mac and getting stuck on the installation of the datastore

```
virtualenv gcd
gcd/bin/pip install googledatastore
```

I get an error

```
Downloading/unpacking googledatastore
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googledatastore (from versions: v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0, v1beta1-rev2-1.0.1, v1beta2-rev1-2.0.0, v1beta2-rev1-2.1.0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for googledatastore
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/ryan/.pip/pip.log
```

In the log ~/.pip/pip.log there is quite a bit and it ends off with

```
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 322, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions matching the version for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions matching the version for googledatastore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is: pip install --pre googledatastore

I will leave the question up because I did not find this in my google search here is my source. It is not quite a duplicate but close

Source for solution: [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz)

Answer (score 1):

Might be off topic, but you may be interested in [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) ([documentation](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/)).