# Why am I getting errors when trying to install FiPy?

Tags: python, fipy

I have tried for hours to install `FiPy`
I've installed Pip and many other things to get it to work. Pip successfull installed many of the things I needed but I cannot get it to work for PySparse or FiPy. Why I try, to install PySparse I get an error:

```
$ pip install pysparse
Downloading/unpacking pysparse
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysparse (from versions: 1.1.1-dev, 1.2-dev, 1.2-dev202, 1.2-dev203, 1.2-dev213, 1.3-dev)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pysparse
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Emily/.pip/pip.log
```

and when I try to install `FiPy` I get this error:

```
$ pip install fipy
Downloading/unpacking fipy
  Downloading FiPy-3.1.tar.gz (5.7MB): 5.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/jt/gzhjdv8s1xb_v2b52lmr8bx00000gn/T/pip_build_Emily/fipy/setup.py) egg_info for package fipy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jt/gzhjdv8s1xb_v2b52lmr8bx00000gn/T/pip_build_Emily/fipy/setup.py", line 44, in <module>
        import ez_setup
    ImportError: No module named ez_setup
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/jt/gzhjdv8s1xb_v2b52lmr8bx00000gn/T/pip_build_Emily/fipy/setup.py", line 44, in <module>

    import ez_setup

ImportError: No module named ez_setup

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jt/gzhjdv8s1xb_v2b52lmr8bx00000gn/T/pip_build_Emily/fipy
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Emily/.pip/pip.log
```

Can you please help? Please be specific because I am having a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I've just encountered the same problems you did, and here are my work-arounds:

Pysparse:
pip doesn't find the pysparse distribution in PyPI because it appears to not be a stable version (see e.g. [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz) for reference). To get around this you could use, as the link suggests,

```
pip install --pre pysparse
```

However, that didn't work for me--the installation failed.
So I downloaded and installed pysparse manually from http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/index.html

FiPY:
The error says "no module named ez_setup". If you install the python ez_setup module using pip the installation of FiPY should now work.

FiPY seems to be working for me now. Good luck!

Comment: PySparse can be `pip install`ed by
```
pip install -e git+http://git.code.sf.net/p/pysparse/git#egg=PySparse
```

Answer (score 1):

PySparse is not a strict requirement for FiPy. FiPy needs one of PySparse, Scipy or Trilinos as a linear solver and Scipy is probably the easiest to install. To check that FiPy has access to a linear solver, you can run the tests,

```
$ python -c "import fipy; fipy.test()"
```

It should be evident from the test output if FiPy does not have a solver library available.