# No distributions at all found for setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I'm having an issue with `pip install`. I am trying to download `SQLAlchemy` and download the gz file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy/1.0.5). However, when I type `pip install setup.py` in the Command Prompt, I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking setup.py 
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement setup.py
Cleaning up..
No distributions at all found for setup.py
```

I've been facing a similar problem with `pip` when trying to download other libraries and this started occurring a day after I downloaded Python 3.4, when I was running Python 2.7 previously. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz) and tried using `pip install --pre library_name`. However, this doesn't seem to working either and I get a similar message to the one above.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wrong command. Please do

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Or:

```
python setup.py install  # If you want to manually extract the package for installation for some reason, but this is not required with pip
```

Comment: python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy works fine for me on Ubuntu (my default is Python2).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thanks. I tried the first command you suggested and I get the following message: `Successfully installed SQLAlchemy                            Cleaning up..                         Exception` and then a lot of description about the Exception.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error info, preferably as Markdown code block.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I reopened my Command Prompt and it worked. Don't understand what was happening. Thank You.