# pip install pandas fails as part of a larger requirements.txt

Tags: pandas, pip

I get an error I don't understand when using pip --install to a install a set of requirements. The error message is shown at the bottom of my message, and seems to implicate pandas.  But I can install pandas by itself (pip install panda) and I get no errors.

I'm doing this testing via a virgin virtual environment. Here is my requirements.txt:

```
absl-py
numpy  
matplotlib 
seaborn
pip
scipy  
scikit-learn
gspread
google-colab
pip
# pytz
# pytz >= 2011k  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz
pandas 
google-auth
traitlets
# google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
```

I'm confused.  I'm running Python 3.10.12 on a Ubuntu, and pip 22.0.2.

Why is this pip install -r requirements.txt failing?  And why is Pandas getting the blame? I need a set of requirements that I can use for GitHub actions, so no special munging allowed, I believe, since the only control I have is via requirements.txt.

Thanks.

-- Malcolm

```
malcolm@instance-1:~/Projects/StanfordAudiology$ python -m venv ./venv
malcolm@instance-1:~/Projects/StanfordAudiology$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) malcolm@instance-1:~/Projects/StanfordAudiology$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting absl-py
  Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (18.2 MB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.6 MB)
Collecting seaborn
  Using cached seaborn-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (22.0.2)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.11.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (36.4 MB)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.3.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (10.8 MB)
Collecting gspread
  Using cached gspread-5.11.3-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Collecting google-colab
  Using cached google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.3 MB)
Collecting google-auth
  Using cached google_auth-2.23.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (182 kB)
Collecting traitlets
  Using cached traitlets-5.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-10.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.6 MB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Using cached fonttools-4.43.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (301 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting joblib>=1.1.1
  Using cached joblib-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (302 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gspread to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting gspread
  Using cached gspread-5.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gspread to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached gspread-5.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting google-auth
  Using cached google_auth-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib==0.5.3
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from google-auth->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (59.6.0)
Collecting six>=1.9.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-auth-oauthlib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-auth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting gspread
  Using cached gspread-5.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached gspread-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached gspread-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached gspread-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached gspread-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached gspread-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached gspread-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.2.1
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting gspread
  Using cached gspread-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
  Using cached gspread-3.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting google-auth
  Using cached google_auth-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting ipykernel~=4.6.0
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting ipython~=5.5.0
  Using cached ipython-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (758 kB)
Collecting notebook~=5.2.0
  Using cached notebook-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting gspread
  Using cached gspread-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scikit-learn to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (10.8 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.11.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (36.3 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pip to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of seaborn to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting seaborn
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (293 kB)
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (285 kB)
  Using cached seaborn-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (292 kB)
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting portpicker~=1.2.0
  Using cached portpicker-1.2.0.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests~=2.21.0
  Using cached requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting six~=1.12.0
  Using cached six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting tornado~=4.5.0
  Using cached tornado-4.5.3.tar.gz (484 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pytz>=2011k
  Using cached pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
Collecting cachetools>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-5.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting rsa>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client
  Using cached jupyter_client-8.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting pexpect
  Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting pygments
  Using cached Pygments-2.16.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-1.0.18-py3-none-any.whl (245 kB)
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8
  Using cached simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip (12 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pickleshare
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting nbformat
  Using cached nbformat-5.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting nbconvert
  Using cached nbconvert-7.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (256 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting terminado>=0.3.3
  Using cached terminado-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting jinja2
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting ipython-genutils
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.6.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.24.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Using cached wcwidth-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting ptyprocess
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting terminado>=0.3.3
  Using cached terminado-0.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
  Using cached terminado-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
  Using cached terminado-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
  Using cached terminado-0.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Collecting pyzmq>=23.0
  Using cached pyzmq-25.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)

...

Collecting platformdirs>=2.5
  Using cached platformdirs-3.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting tinycss2
  Using cached tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
  Using cached nbclient-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Collecting defusedxml
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting mistune<4,>=2.0.3
  Using cached mistune-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting bleach!=5.0.0
  Using cached bleach-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=2.6
  Using cached jsonschema-4.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting fastjsonschema
  Using cached fastjsonschema-2.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting webencodings
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting rpds-py>=0.7.1
  Using cached rpds_py-0.10.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting attrs>=22.2.0
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting jsonschema-specifications>=2023.03.6
  Using cached jsonschema_specifications-2023.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting referencing>=0.28.4
  Using cached referencing-0.30.2-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Using cached soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for google-colab, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pandas, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for portpicker, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for tornado, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for simplegeneric, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: webencodings, wcwidth, tornado, simplegeneric, pytz, ptyprocess, portpicker, pickleshare, ipython-genutils, fastjsonschema, chardet, urllib3, traitlets, tinycss2, threadpoolctl, terminado, soupsieve, six, rpds-py, pyzmq, pyparsing, pygments, pyasn1, platformdirs, pillow, pexpect, pandocfilters, packaging, numpy, nest-asyncio, mistune, MarkupSafe, kiwisolver, jupyterlab-pygments, joblib, idna, fonttools, entrypoints, defusedxml, decorator, cycler, certifi, cachetools, attrs, absl-py, scipy, rsa, requests, referencing, python-dateutil, pyasn1-modules, prompt-toolkit, jupyter-core, jinja2, contourpy, bleach, beautifulsoup4, scikit-learn, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-client, jsonschema-specifications, ipython, google-auth, seaborn, jsonschema, ipykernel, gspread, nbformat, nbclient, nbconvert, notebook, google-colab
  Running setup.py install for tornado ... done
  Running setup.py install for simplegeneric ... done
  Running setup.py install for portpicker ... done
  Running setup.py install for pandas ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pandas did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1010 lines of output]
      running install
      /home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas
      copying pandas/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas
      copying pandas/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas
      copying pandas/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas
....

      UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas/_version.py
      set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas/_version.py to '0.24.2'
      running build_ext
      building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas/_libs
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c pandas/_libs/algos.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/pandas/_libs/algos.o -Wno-unused-function
      In file included from /home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1929,
                       from /home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                       from /home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:5,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:637:
      /home/malcolm/Projects/StanfordAudiology/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
         17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
            |  ^~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_array’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:155771:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
      155771 |     ++Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:155773:5: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
      155773 |     --Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_memoryview’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:156060:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
      156060 |     ++Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:156062:5: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
      156062 |     --Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc__memoryviewslice’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:156299:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
      156299 |     ++Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:156301:5: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
      156301 |     --Py_REFCNT(o);
             |     ^~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__Pyx_modinit_type_init_code’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:158842:70: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      158842 |   __pyx_scope_struct____Pyx_CFunc_object____ndarray____object___to_py.tp_print = 0;
             |                                                                      ^
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:158850:25: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      158850 |   __pyx_type___pyx_array.tp_print = 0;
             |                         ^
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:158855:31: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      158855 |   __pyx_type___pyx_MemviewEnum.tp_print = 0;
             |                               ^
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:158870:30: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      158870 |   __pyx_type___pyx_memoryview.tp_print = 0;
             |                              ^
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:158883:35: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      158883 |   __pyx_type___pyx_memoryviewslice.tp_print = 0;
             |                                   ^
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__Pyx_ParseOptionalKeywords’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164747:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164747 |                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                     ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
        580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
            |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:164763:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      164763 |                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
             |                         ^
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pandas/_libs/algos.c: In function ‘__Pyx_decode_c_string’:
      pandas/_libs/algos.c:167625:9: warning: ‘PyUnicode_FromUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      167625 |         return PyUnicode_FromUnicode(NULL, 0);
             |         ^~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                       from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from pandas/_libs/algos.c:38:
      /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
        551 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
            |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pandas

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Success.

Removed unneccessary imports (and requirements). Most importantly, not including google_colab seemed like the most important factor.

Not sure who broke what, but fewer imports is a winning strategy.

[I can't find the link to the obligatory xkcd strip documenting this idea.]